# How many non-homeomorphic surfaces arise from these graphs?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-geometry

Take an undirected graph $G$, where every vertex has at least two edges (we count self-loops as two edges). For each vertex $v$, we define a regular deg($v$)-gon. For each edge between $v_1$ and $v_2$, we glue one of the edges of their polygon together (arbitrarily). We never glue an edge to itself.

This will give us a surface (which will be compact if $G$ is finite). How many surfaces will there be, up to homeomorphism (or how do you calculate this number, or establish bounds on it)?

Note that different surfaces can pop up, depending on how you glue things together. For example, a vertex with two self-loops, it can be a torus or a Klein bottle or a projective plane or a sphere.

We have $\Pi_{v\in V(G)}2(\text{deg($v$)}-1)!$ as an upper bound (the factor $2$ is because of orientation).

Comment: (singular of vertices is vertex, just fyi)

Comment: The answer is "1". Or maybe you mean, how many when $G$ varies... under which restriction? $G$ ranges over finite graphs? connected? with some restriction on the number of vertices?...

Comment: @YCor I mean if you connect them in different orders. For example, Imagine that $G$ is a vertex $v$ with four self loops. Then the topology could be a torus, klein bottle, projective plane, or even sphere.

Comment: For each vertex, to define a polygon, you need some cyclic ordering of the set of edges at this vertex. So this sounds ill-defined.

Comment: Ah that's the point. Please edit to clarify so that we can wipe out these comments.

Comment: The number of cyclic orderings at a given vertex $v$ of degree $d$ is much more than $2d$. It's $d!/d=(d-1)!$.

Comment: @YCor Does that clear things up?

Comment: No more "2": the number of cyclic ordering up to orientation is $(d-1)!/2$. The number of cyclic orderings (oriented) is $(d-1)!$, not $2(d-1)!$.

Comment: @YCor I mean choosing whether or not to twist the edge before you connect it. For example, a vertice with one self-loop can connect to form either an orientable or a non-orientable surface. So it has 2(2-1)!=2 different topologies.

Comment: You seem to mean that you allow orientations on edges that are not cyclic. Then the number of possible choices for one vertex is $2^{d-1}(d-1)!$ which is still much larger. Here it means: $(d-1)!/2$ choices of cyclic ordering up to orientation, times $2^d$ choices of orientation. Actually, the huge product that comes is too big because changing the orientation of one edge and the incident edge does not change the resulting space. So one should get something such as $2^e\prod_v((\deg(v)-1)!/2)$, where $e$ is the total number of non-oriented edges.

Comment: I've edited the title since a "topology" usually means a collection of open sets satisfying certain conditions.

Comment: This *somewhat* related question, "[Fundamental polygons with infinite pairwise identifications](https://mathoverflow.net/q/37721/6094)," is notable because Bill Thurston posted [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/38394/6094). Any insight into his reasoning is worthwhile.

Comment: Something is off... you say "we count self-loops as two edges"... so does that mean you count "four self-loops" as eight edges?

Comment: @LeeMosher Oh, yeah. Whoops!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are trying to enumerate ribbon graphs, in which case you might want to look at:

*Do, Norman; Manescu, David*, [**Quantum curves for the enumeration of ribbon graphs and hypermaps**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/CNTP.2014.v8.n4.a2), Commun. Number Theory Phys. 8, No. 4, 677-701 (2014). [ZBL1366.14034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1366.14034).

There is an arxiv.org version: [arXiv:1312.6869](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.6869).